# Is possible reset the session time [instead of 20 min]/ or set session time more then 4 hours in c# MVC webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

From login time, session should maintain next 4 hours using c# MVC web application

```
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            ctx.Session.Timeout = 240;
```

Comment: Are you using .net core?

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config file, you can set the session timeout value to 240 (minutes).

But the application pool may restart even before the session timeout. In that case, the session will restart if the application pool is restarted.

So, we need to increase the application pool timeout as well in the IIS.